# error when serializing calendar event

Tags: python, caldav, vobject

I am trying to modify calendars using the python caldav library (version 0.5.0) on python 2.7. I am using the following code snippet to add an exdate to recurring events

```
for event in results:
    vevent = event.instance.vevent
    if vevent.status.value != "CANCELLED":
        if (vevent.summary.value, vevent.dtstart.value) in cancelled:
            ev = calendar.event_by_uid(vevent.uid.value)
            ev.instance.vevent.add("exdate").value = vevent.dtstart.value
            print ev.instance.vevent.serialize()
```

Although the vobject library claims support for datetime objects the last line fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./caldavTest.py", line 31, in <module>
    print ev.instance.vevent.serialize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py", line 254, in serialize
    return behavior.serialize(self, buf, lineLength, validate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/behavior.py", line 166, in serialize
    out = base.defaultSerialize(transformed, buf, lineLength)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py", line 1007, in defaultSerialize
    child.serialize(outbuf, lineLength, validate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py", line 254, in serialize
    return behavior.serialize(self, buf, lineLength, validate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/behavior.py", line 160, in serialize
    transformed = obj.transformFromNative()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py", line 226, in transformFromNative
    raise NativeError(msg, lineNumber)
vobject.base.NativeError: "In transformFromNative, unhandled exception on line None <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't this be reported to its maintainer first?

Comment: maybe, but is this a python-caldav or a vobject issue or just me not understanding the API?

Comment: I guess the maintainers of both projects know the best answer.

Comment: I gave it a try at https://github.com/eventable/vobject/issues/107

Comment: nice shot, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In *vobject*, the value of an EXDATE property is a *list* of datetime values.

So, instead of:

```
ev.instance.vevent.add("exdate").value = vevent.dtstart.value
```

your code should do something like:

```
ev.instance.vevent.add("exdate").value.append(vevent.dtstart.value)
```

This avoids the exception reported during serialization.